# MySQL Query Issue - PHP variable not passed through includes

Tags: php, mysql

So as the title suggests, I am having trouble executing a MySQL query. The query works almost successfully, as all data fields are stored into my database except for one. The query itself is a commenting system for signed in users to comment on any given blog post. The issue I am having is that the variable '$post_id' is not recognized, and therefore '$comment_post_ID' is not stored in my database.

'$post_id' is defined in blogs.php, and after echoing this variable it does exist and is successfully defined. However, this variable is not passed onto commentsubmit.php, which is included in the same file where the variable is defined. Why is this happening?

Here are all the pieces of my code:

blogs.php (shows all posts from all users, or just one post if ?id is set in the url. If ?id is set, users can comment on the single post they are viewing.)

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword", "mydbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}

$post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

$blog_post = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE id = '$post_id'";
$blog_query = mysqli_query($conn, $blog_post);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($blog_query)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    $author_username = $row['author_username'];
    $datetime = time_ago($row['datetime'], $granularity=2);
}

include ("./fullpageblog.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {   
    include ("./blogcomment.php");
    include ("./commentsubmit.php");
}

echo "$post_id";

mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

blogcomment.php (form for users to make a comment)

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
<div id="fullPageBlog">     
    <div id="center-border"></div>
        <form action="commentsubmit.php" method="post">
            <textarea maxlength="1000" id="blogComment" name="content" placeholder="Write your response..."></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="comment" value="Publish" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">$('#blogPost').elastic();</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

commentsubmit.php (comment query itself)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword", "mydbname");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }

    $comment_post_ID = $post_id;
    $comment_author = $_SESSION['full_name'];
    $comment_author_email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $comment_author_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $comment_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $comment_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['content']);
    $user_ID = $_SESSION['id'];

    $comment_submit = "INSERT INTO comments (comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_author_username, comment_date, comment_content, user_ID) VALUES ('', '$comment_post_ID', '$comment_author', '$comment_author_email', '$comment_author_username', '$comment_date', '$comment_content', '$user_ID') ";
    $comment_query = mysqli_query($conn, $comment_submit);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    header("Location: blogs.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: $post_id isn't defined in your commentsubmit.php file, You should be getting this from $_POST or something by adding a hidden field or appending it to url like this ``?post_id=$post_id`` when generating that view.

Comment: what comment_postID? You do `$comment_post_id = $post_id`, but never define `$post_id` anywhere. So you're effectively doing `$comment_post_id = null`. And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). you're not escaping everything you should be.

Comment: $post_id is defined in blogs.php, I have tried defining it again in commentsubmit.php using the same line of code: $post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']); but this did not work.

Comment: Because you process with a `POST` not a `GET` in the commentssubmit; you also have no element named `id` that I can see in your form.

Comment: I do not see why I would use GET instead of POST? I use POST to submit other forms in different areas of this project and it works perfectly.

Comment: You said you used `$post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);`. Your form says `<form action="commentsubmit.php" method="post">` so `$_GET` will never be set. Also `['id']` doesn't exist.

Comment: ['id'] does exist, and is pulled from the URL successfully in the first block of code I have shown, blogs.php. With this the '$post_id' is defined, and certainly does exist, I have it echoed on the page. The problem is this variable is not being passed to the included file, which it should, according to PHP manual.

Comment: What manual entry? Why should it be being passed?

Comment: This is quoted from Variable scope page of the PHP manual. The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. 
For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. 
**This single scope spans included and required files as well.**

Comment: That is for one page and more directed to functions. You are going across multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include/require the `blogs.php` script from the `commentsubmit.php` script, so the code in `blogs.php` would never be run after a POST that is made directly to `commentsubmit.php` unless you have some other request processing (i.e. a server-side rewrite or similar) that happens automatically on the server before the request ultimately reaches the portion of code shown in `commentsubmit.php` above.

Answer (score -2):

```
 <?php
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
     $con=mysql_select_db("database_name");
     error_reporting(0);
     session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $comment_author = $_POST['full_name'];
     $comment_author_email = $_POST['email'];
     $comment_author_username = $_POST['username'];

    $sql="select * from table_name where `full_name`='"$comment_author "',`email`='"$comment_author_email "',`username`='"$comment_author_username "'";
    $qur=mysql_query($sql);
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($qur);
    $num= mysql_num_rows($qur);
}
 if($num>0){

 $_SESSION["full_name"]=$full_name;
 $_SESSION["email"]=$comment_author_email;
 $_SESSION["username"]=$comment_author_username;
 }
else{
  echo"Username and Password are wrong";
 }

?>
```

Comment: You made SQL injections much more executable and downgraded the OP's database driver,why?

Comment: How can  you say that SQL injections much more executable and downgraded the OP's database driver.

Comment: You are using `mysql_connect`. OP is using `mysqli_connect`. BIG difference. See the warnings, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php. OP is using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You are sending user data direct to the DB without any sort of escaping so a user could insert anything they wanted.